# Is a Translation Unit always a file?

Tags: c++, assembly, translation-unit

In C++, when I ask someone what a translation unit is, the popular response is that it is usually a source file. `static` and `extern` modify how global functions and variables are accessed by other translation units. Can translation units be something else, too? For example, an assembly file (not .cpp with inline ASM)? Or a .dll? I've seen experienced software engineers make such programs.

My experience with C++ is largely with microcontrollers, so I am used to making a main.cpp, some .h files, and including a few libraries from PIO or GitHub, but not using ASM.

Another source of confusion, some say that all of the includes are also part of the same translation unit. If that were so, then `static` and `extern` would not behave the way I believe they do now. I would really like to clear some of the confusion associated with translation units.

Comment: A translation file is commonly a single source file with all included header files. The object file created by the compiler is the result. Also see e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: A translation unit is something that (with mainstream compilers) can compile to a separate `.o` / `.obj`.  It includes all the code that compiled to that `.o`, including everything you `#include`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude *Commonly* is the important word there. I've, in the past, worked on systems where system libraries were not filesystem files, but pulled from a database by the compiler. Those were still "*compilation units*", but they were not *files* (in the filesystem). IIRC, that was on a IBM AS/400 system or maybe it was a S/390 mainframe - I don't exactly remember; it was 15+ years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is a Translation Unit always a file?

No, it does not have to be. For example, the standard library headers (and other source files) could in theory *not* be files in the filesystem. They could be something internal to the compiler, contained within the compiler executable, or found in a database, or whatever. A translation unit is *usually* a source file, but you cannot assume that.

> Another source of confusion, some say that all of the includes are also part of the same translation unit

Sure they are. When a source file is compiled, the preprocessor has already run and basically copy+paste'd all the includes into the source file that the compiler sees. So, from the compiler's perspective, the includes *are* part of the compilation unit, since all their contents were pasted into the file the compiler was given. The compiler never sees `#include` directives - those are all handled by the preprocessor before the compiler ever sees the file/translation unit.

See also:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/extern

Comment: Ok, so if they are all the same translation unit, then how does `static` and `extern` even work?

Comment: @MJTech `extern` works by telling the compiler "the symbol you see here declared as extern; assume it exists somewhere else" and `static` works by telling the compiler "this symbol is local to this compilation unit - if it exists elsewhere, don't worry about it, that would be a bug by the programmer and you don't have to worry about that". C++ places a lot of trust in "the programmer" and the compiler is allowed to assume that the programmer knows what they are doing (and if they don't, then that's a bug the compiler doesn't need to worry about).

Comment: @MJTech: `static foo(int x){ static int firstcall = x; return ++firstcall; }` in a header gives each source file that `#include`s it its own private copy of that function, exactly as if you copy/pasted that code into each file separately.  I chose an example where that makes a difference; each copy of the function has its own private counter.  Otherwise it matters for optimization if not inlined; normally you'd prefer a function to be defined once in the whole program, not have separate copies of the machine code.  (C++ has the `inline` keyword to make that convenient.)

Comment: compilation vs translation unit?

Comment: Read up on the One Definition Rule - aka ODR.

Comment: @MJTech Do recall that the compiler is not the whole show, there is also the linker. A translation unit is what the compiler translates (to intermediate form) in one go. The linker sews one or more pieces together into one program. Basically: for statics, the compiler doesn't need to include information in its output to allow the linker to connect references from other translation units to it; for externs, the compiler flags uses for the linker to connect up to the object from another translation unit(could be from a library).

Comment: Remember; There are 3 stages to compilation of a C++ program - 1) preprocessing. 2) compilation. 3) linking.

Comment: in what case do i actually get multiple translation units if all includes are placed in my main.cpp anyway? that's my pain point. what do those two keywords do if i only have one translation unit?

Comment: @MJTech If you only have *one* compilation unit comprising your entire program, then those keywords are close to irrelevant.

Comment: thank you. and how do i get multiple units? do i need cmake? would I get dlls (or equivalent) as a result?

Comment: @MJTech "how do i get multiple units?" - Add more source files that are preprocessed/compiled individually. CMake is irrelevant in that question - cmake is a *build system* it just deals in how to process and compile files, not in what are compilation units for the compiler.

Comment: when i use platformio for a microcontroller, i get one binary to upload, so these multiple units are foreign to me. do i get multiple outputs, or just multiple compilations that get linked?

Comment: @MJTech Multiple compilation units are usually *linked* to form a *library* or *executable*. That's what you usually run (or load from the program you are running). Your "one binary" is what the linker produces. You really need to read up on the C++ compilation process/model..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256607/discussion-between-mjtech-and-jesper-juhl).

Answer (score 6):

From [C++20 standard draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf#page.49):

> The text of the program is kept in units called *source files* in this document. A source file together with
> all the headers (16.5.1.2) and source files included (15.3) via the preprocessing directive `#include`, less any
> source lines skipped by any of the conditional inclusion (15.2) preprocessing directives, is called a *translation
> unit*. [Note: A C++ program need not all be translated at the same time. — end note]

So in general, translation unit is one C++ file together with all of its `#include`d headers passed as input to C++ compiler. This is then translated (compiled). After translating all translation units, one can link them together to form a program.

---

Assembly file is not C++ and not considered by C++ standard. If a toolchain would link that to C++ program, it's that toolchain extension.

DLL (and other libraries) is a set of one or more already translated translation units. It can be linked with other translated translation units into a program.

Comment: Plus one for citing the standard :)

Comment: Did you run across anything in the Standard that describes how modules fit into the picture?

Comment: @tbxfreeware That's an entire section of definitions, hard to fit in comment :) https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf#chapter.10 . In short: translation unit with module-definition is a module unit. All module units with the same name are a named module. If I read correctly, translation units with `module;` (unnamed module?) are global module fragments, and all of those + all non-module translation units are a global module. A module is a named module or the global module. Seems like everything a module is, and I wrote that word far too many times already

Comment: Thanks. The short answer is fine: _a translation unit with module-definition is a module unit._ Thus, a module unit _is_ a translation unit (if I have that right!).